# Проверка открыт ли файл

Tags: python

я открываю файл следующим образом

```
with open(link, 'rb') as file:
  file_data = file.read()
```

иногда бывают файлы к которым нет прав на чтение и программа вылетает,
как проверить открыт ли файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try:
    with open(link, 'rb') as file:
        file_data = file.read()
except PermissionError:
    print('Нет прав на чтение файла')
```